# Fish shell and rvm - allowing login shell

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, rvm, fish

When I try to use rvm in fish shell, I get this message:

> ciembor@ciembor ~> rvm use 1.9.2
>
> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not
>   work.
>
> You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login
>   shell. Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the
>   command. Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a
>   example.

I get used to use `/bin/bash --login`, then `rvm` and then starting `fish` from `bash`. But isn't there more straightforward way? I use xfce4 terminal.

Comment: The way rvm is implemented doesn't work very well with non-posix compatible shells.

I would suggest you go for something like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby), or something implemented in fish - [fry](https://github.com/terlar/fry) (self-promotion)

Comment: There is now fish integration for rvm http://rvm.io/integration/fish

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Download the rvm fish function from GitHub:

```
curl --create-dirs -o ~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish https://raw.github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/master/functions/rvm.fish
```

Reference: http://rvm.io/integration/fish

Answer (score 3):

Download the fish functions from GitHub.

```
curl -L --create-dirs -o ~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish https://raw.github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/master/functions/rvm.fish
```

And activate the default Ruby manually in your config.fish file:

```
echo "rvm default" >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

And you're done

Answer (score 0):

Try look at bash "initialization" files like ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile and session "initialization" files ~/.profile /etc/profile* and add rvm related code(something like

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

) to fish "initialization" file ~/.config/fish/config.fish

Comment: I don't see anything like that in .bashrc etc. There is also no `.rvm` directory in my home. rvm is stored here: `ciembor@ciembor ~> whereis rvm`
`rvm: /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`

Comment: It sounds like you installed rvm as root. You should look into the multi-user documentation on RVMs site.