# Fish RVM Use error

Tags: rvm, fish

So I installed fish and oh-my-fish, and when i want to use rvm I get this error:

```
➜ avalancha git:(services) ✗ rvm use 2.1.0

Using /home/matias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
fish: The '$' character begins a variable name. The character '{', which directly followed a '$', is not allowed as a part of a variable name, and variable names may not be zero characters long. To learn more about variable expansion in fish, type 'help expand-variable'.
/home/matias/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish (line 2): begin; set -xg rvm_bin_path "/home/matias/.rvm/bin" ; set -xg GEM_HOME "/home/matias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0" ; set -xg XDG_SESSION_PATH "/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0" ; set -xg rvm_path "/home/matias/.rvm" ; set -xg XDG_SEAT_PATH "/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0" ; set -xg DEFAULTS_PATH "/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path" ; set -xg rvm_prefix "/home/matias" ; set -xg PATH "/home/matias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin" "/home/matias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin" "/home/matias/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin" "/home/matias/.rvm/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/bin" "/usr/games" "/usr/local/games" ; set -xg MANDATORY_PATH "/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path" ; set -xg rvm_version "1.25.29 stable" ; set -xg rvm_ruby_string "ruby-2.1.0" ; set -xg GEM_PATH "/home/matias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0" "/home/matias/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global" ; set -xg rvm_delete_flag "0" ; set -xg rvm_debug " {  (( ${rvm_debug_flag:-0} )) || return 0;" ; ;end eval2_inner <&3 3<&-
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
in . (source) call of file '-',
    called on line 22 of file '/home/matias/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish',

in function 'rvm',
    called on standard input,
    with parameter list 'use 2.1.0'

.: Error while reading file '-'
```

Does anyone know what could it be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fish shell and rvm - allowing login shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824764/fish-shell-and-rvm-allowing-login-shell)

Comment: No, I already added the Fish integration functions for RVM. It's not asking me to login in bash.

Comment: It looks like they modified the way the rvm_debug flag was set and didn't modify the sed invocation that replaces all bash syntax with fish syntax in the env setting. This probably needs to be opened as an issue on the rvm issue tracker

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue. It's an incompatibility caused by the multiline value of the `rvm_debug` variable. I patched the function to ignore this variable completely by making a small change.

Open **~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish** and change **line 7** from this:

```
and eval (grep '^rvm\|^[^=]*PATH\|^GEM_HOME' $env_file | grep -v '_clr=' | sed '/^[^=]*PATH/s/:/" "/g; s/^/set -xg /; s/=/ "/; s/$/" ;/; s/(//; s/)//')
```

into this:

```
and eval (grep '^rvm\|^[^=]*PATH\|^GEM_HOME' $env_file | grep -v '_clr=' | grep -v 'rvm_debug=' | sed '/^[^=]*PATH/s/:/" "/g; s/^/set -xg /; s/=/ "/; s/$/" ;/; s/(//; s/)//')
```

I don't know what `rvm_debug` is being used for, but my system seems to work without it.